# Frame size property not working

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I have a little problem, I am trying to set an image inside a frame to the frame's size.
However, the Width and Height properties return garbage.

What am I doing wrong?
See gw, gh:

[image]

Comment: Has is been drawn yet at that point? If it hasn't been drawn then those will return garbage. In the ExtendedSplash examle, they have you wait for the OnResize event before setting the image size if I remember correctly. Then you also have the ability to use the event args for the resizing.

Comment: I'm trying that right now, however the new method is never called. Using WindowSizeChangedEventHandler.

Comment: Well I got it. you have to use WindowActivatedEventHandler and then get the size using ActualWidth/ActualHeight and not Width/Height. Whew this OS is a pain. Post your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for the `WindowActivatedEventHandler` to get the size using `ActualWidth`/`ActualHeight`. This ensures that the `Window` is activated and the `Frame` has been drawn before trying to get the height/width.